# topOffset not working when clicking an anchor link from a different page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function that enables smooth scrolling within a page by selecting all hrefs that include a #. On click the page scrolls down to the linked section, minus a top-offset of the height of my header (because it has a position: fixed; ). 
Now my problem is that this offset gets ignored when I link to a section on a different page.

I'm guessing the problem is my `click(function()` parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {

    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);

      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - $('#main_menu').height()
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

How can I make it so that the topOffset for my header doesn't get disregarded when I click on a link that leades to a section on a different page (like e.g. when I'm on `contact.html` and go to `index.html#sectionA`)?

Comment: Are you sure that the topOffset has a height? Try doing a console.log of the variable to check if it has a height.

Comment: I'm not sure how to console.log this exactly... But within the same page, scrolling minds the topOffset just fine. It also works when I use a number as offset, e.g. 250px. It just doesn't work from a different page, no matter if I use a number or .height() - Edit: Never mind that first bit, the console.log tells me the height is 179px.